# Can I move my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS OS to my SSD? (From HD)

Tags: ubuntu, windows

I am currently dual booting windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. My windows is on my SSD and when I tried to add Ubuntu not too long ago there was only 2gb available shrink space on my SSD. So I thought I would just use the free space on my other HD, and make a free partition there. I just wanted to see how Ubuntu was, how it ran, looked and all that. Am extremely impressed and would like to use it on my SSD for the even better performance, while keeping the dual boot windows for gaming and a few other things. So my question Is there a way to move my current Ubuntu OS onto my SSD? (Now that Ive got 10gb shrink space on my SSD, if that's enough). 
Or would it just be easier to delete the old Ubuntu, create the free shrink space only on my SSD and reinstall it there?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/640259/how-can-i-easily-clone-my-entire-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to Linux world & you don't want to do some complex stuffs, then you should erase the old Ubuntu and install Ubuntu in the SSD. That should be easy step and a safe one. There are many tools out there you can use but these are the ways I have hands-on experience.

If you are okay with the complex steps you can use dd or Clonezilla utility.

dd steps: [Steps](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/copy-your-linux-install-different-partition-or-drive) 
Clonezilla steps: [Link1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41tTudaQb0I) [Link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LS6VhLDw-io)

**Note: Make sure you don't erase your Windows OS partition & when you clone make sure the destination SSD disk free size should be more than source Ubuntu partition size.**

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it but I'll probably take the safer route and reinstall.